# Pages not turning while using turn.js library

Tags: javascript, jquery

What the issue over here even if I have used proper CDN jquery?
The pages are not at all turning and each time I am unable to solve the issue, since I am new to JS, please explain what mistake I am doing here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Bookshelf/turn.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #magazine {
            width: 800px;
            height: 400px;
        }

        #magazine .turn-page {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="magazine">
        <div><span class="text">Page 1</span></div>
        <div><span class="text">Page 2</span></div>
        <div><span class="text">Page 3</span></div>
    </div>

    **Are there any issue over here?**

    <script>$('#magazine').turn({ gradients: true, acceleration: true });</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi there R P and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you could create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then we could run your code and see what goes wrong. Also, make sure to open the console in your developer tools to see if any errors are reported.

Comment: I will keep your suggestion in mind Emiel, there are no errors shown in the console. The pages are not turning, thats the major problem.

Comment: according to [demo](https://github.com/elaxman/bookshelf/blob/master/demos/magazine/index.html) try to use jquery wrapper of ready state `$(window).ready(function() {...})`

Comment: Still not working even after using the jquery wrapper of ready state